# php script to validate multiple facebook access tokens

Tags: facebook, validation

I am trying to find a way to automatically validate multiple facebook access tokens at once.

I am storing user access tokens into sql database and (as expected) after some time some of the tokens will expire or becomes invalid. (due to user change password/de-authorized app, log out, etc.)

Is there any way to check/validate all access tokens from a `.txt` file/database and delete those tokens that are invalid: doing this manually for more than 100 tokens is very difficult.

Options

1. checking access tokens from a `.txt` file (using PHP) and remove invalid tokens simultaneously so that at the end we will have a list with only valid tokens.
2. directly remove invalid tokens from the database.

Any insight?

This has become a very common problem now a days not only me but most of us are still googling like i did before posting it here but no one has ever found a way to solve this problem and i believe is this is the only forum where this thing can be fixed.

Comment: I would think the "correct way" to do this would be to check the response from Facebook any time you try to use a token and mark the token as invalid if the response indicates as such.  There shouldn't be a need to manually validate the current state of the tokens, Facebook should tell you which ones are invalid when the application tries to use them in its normal operations.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no endpoint where you could check multiple tokens at once. The most similar method to achieve the functionality you want is to [batch the requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/). You should be good to batch them in sets of 25.

So, your flow would be this: Get 25 tokens from the SQL database. Call `/me` endpoint with each token. IE, your batch call with look like

> batch=[{"method":"GET","relative_url":"me?fields=id&access_token=TOKEN1"},{"method":"GET","relative_url":"me?fields=id&access_token=TOKEN2"},...,{"method":"GET","relative_url":"me?fields=id&access_token=TOKEN25"}]

Loop through the response, if its checks out, you're good. If an error is thrown, its not. Deal with each access_token accordingly. The responses will be in the same order as you gave Facebook.

Comment: thanks for your reply...
I don't know how to say...
but to be honest I'am not that good at coding...This is a very common problem that everyone is facing now a days....so if some one could give me full code that would be more than enough..